# Where can I find the full text of the interview of Sheikh Mujibur Rahman with Oriana Fallaci?

Tags: reference-request, italy

Several years ago I read an interview in a newspaper of [Sheikh Mujibur Rahman with Oriana Fallaci](https://www.nytimes.com/1973/01/25/archives/oriana-fallaci-an-interviewer-who-goes-for-the-jugular-in-four.html).

Where can I find the full text of this interview?

I thought it was included in the book called [Interview with History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interview_with_History). However, it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

The article on the New York Times is "*Oriana Fallaci, an Interviewer Who Goes for the Jugular in Four Languages*" by Judy Klemesrudthe and you can find it [here](https://www.nytimes.com/1973/01/25/archives/oriana-fallaci-an-interviewer-who-goes-for-the-jugular-in-four.html).

The interview is cited also in the *Dr Abdul Mu'min Chowdhry*, *Behind the Myth of 3 million* ([pdf](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwitlL28_p_4AhXdS_EDHQtSAOgQFnoECAcQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsanipanhwar.com%2FBehind%2520The%2520Myth%2520Of%2520Three%2520Million.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1U5t36WnT6NaKWE-zZ5Mbk)) as

**Oriana Fallaci, An Interview with Mujibur Rahman, L'Europeo, Rome, 24 February, 1972.**

Right now I did not found it anywhere on internet because "L'Europeo" is not active anymore. This answer on [quora](https://it.quora.com/In-quale-libro-di-Oriana-Fallaci-posso-trovare-la-bizzarra-intervista-con-Mujibur-Rahman) tells that is cited in "*Interview with History*" but probably it wasn't published (however I am not sure that is a reliable source).

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the journalistic interview of the New York Times? If so, I doubt you can find it in the [book you mentioned](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intervista_con_la_storia), because that one is rather a collection of interviews made by Oriana Fallaci across her journalistic career.

If you are looking for the text of Judy Klemesrud, I don't know if there is a longer version of the text, but you can always try to contact the author.